# Replace provided string with user input string?

Tags: arrays, c, string, user-input

I will preface this with the fact that this was once working. I added a print statement (now gone) that simply asked the user to input strings.

The input is done through the following method:

```
./Project aa b
```

`aa` was the code to be replaced, and `b` was going to be the letter replacing it for any occurrences in the user's input.

so for

```
./project Timmy Johhny
Timmy strolled through the park
```

the output would be

```
Johhny strolled through the park.
```

And as I said, it did work, and after it just printed spaces.

My code looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * isMatch(char* os, char* ns, char* us){
        int i;
        int oslen, nslen, uslen;
        int it = 0;
        uslen = strlen(us);
        oslen = strlen(os);
        nslen = strlen(ns);
        for(i=0; i < uslen; i++){
                if(strstr(&us[i], os) == &us[i]){
                        it = it + 1;
                        i = i + oslen - 1;
                }
        }
        char *ans = malloc(uslen + nslen * it);
        int anslen = uslen + nslen * it;
        i = 0;
        while(*us){
                if(strstr(us, os) == us){
                        strcpy(&ans[i], ns);
                        i = i + nslen;
                        us = us + oslen;
                }
                else
                        ans[i++] = *us++;



        }
        return ans;                                                                                                                                                    
}


int main(int arg1, char * argp[]){

        char input[100];

        int i;
        char c;


        while(1){
                if(scanf("%c",&c)==EOF){
                        break;
                }
                if( (input[0]=c) != '\n'){
                        for(i=1;i<100;i++){
                                scanf("%c", &input[i]);
                                if(input[i] == '\n'){
                                        break;
                                }

//                            char *match = isMatch(argp[1],argp[2],&input[i]);
//                              printf("%s", match);
//                              free(match);


                        }
                        char *match = isMatch(argp[1],argp[2],&input[i]);
                        printf("%s", match);
                        free(match);

                }

        }
}
```

Is there just a small error I made, or is it something larger.
I tried to move the printf in and out of a for loop amongst everything else, and simply got increasingly strange outputs.

Thank you!

Comment: `uslen = strlen(us);` That results in undefined behaviour because the `input` passed in is not explicitly NUL terminated and hence may not a valid C string. Do basic debugging. Run your code in a debugger and step thru it line by line. You should be able to get much closer to the root cause and be able to describe the approximate location of where things start going wrong.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for your response! Unfortunately that is not the issue. In fact there have been no issues resulting from the strlens. As I said, I did have it running, and running correctly at that.

Comment: That may not be *the* issue but can you see that it definetely is *a* issue? If you don't NUL terminate your string then your code may fail in strange ways at any time. Even if it appears to "work" it will blow up at some point. *I did have it running, and running correctly at that*. That is the exact symptom of Undefined Behaviour - sometimes "works" sometimes doesn't. So it doesn't prove anything.

Comment: @kaylum ah, understood. Apologies. However I am not quite certain what NUL terminated means, or how to apply it.

Comment: Strings in C need to end with a NUL `\0`. Otherwise it is just an array of chars and not a string. Add `input[i]='\0';` before calling `isMatch`.

Comment: `isMatch(argp[1],argp[2],&input[i]);` Oh, this is wrong too. Should be `isMatch(argp[1],argp[2],input);` Errors like this should be picked up by any basic debugging.

Comment: @kaylum You are an absolute champ, and I did learn something new today, thank you very much! So it this something  to do whenever I get user input information.

Comment: @kaylum You should submit this as an answer as well so I can give proper kudos and to help other struggling folks in the future.

Comment: TBH, reading the input one character at a time is not the best way to do things. Just read a whole line with `fgets`.

Comment: @kaylum Great tip for the future as well, thank you!